# Is there an R function for making contingency table for a one multiple choice question?

Tags: r

I need to make a cross table for only one question with multiple choice.

I have a survey results. The idea is to see share of people who know Brand1 also know other brands.

Lets say we have an input table with answers:

```
Id  Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4
1   1       1       0       1
2   0       0       1       1
3   1       1       0       0
4   1       0       0       1
5   0       0       1       1
6   0       0       1       0
7   1       1       0       1
```

We making a cross table with sum of answers for each brand:

```
        Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4
Brand1  4       3       0       3
Brand2  3       3       0       2
Brand3  0       0       3       2
Brand4  3       2       2       5
```

And then calculate the column percent from all who knows each brand:

```
        Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4
Brand1  100%    100%    0%      60%
Brand2  75%     100%    0%      40%
Brand3  0%      0%      100%    40%
Brand4  75%     67%     67%     100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nm = names(d)[-1]
m1 = sapply(nm, function(x) sapply(nm, function(y) sum(d[x] == 1 & d[y] == 1)))
m1
#       Brand1 Brand2 Brand3 Brand4
#Brand1      4      3      0      3
#Brand2      3      3      0      2
#Brand3      0      0      3      2
#Brand4      3      2      2      5
m2 = 100 * sapply(nm, function(x) sapply(nm, function(y)
    sum(d[x] == 1 & d[y] == 1)/sum(d[x] == 1)))
m2
#       Brand1    Brand2    Brand3 Brand4
#Brand1    100 100.00000   0.00000     60
#Brand2     75 100.00000   0.00000     40
#Brand3      0   0.00000 100.00000     40
#Brand4     75  66.66667  66.66667    100
```

---

**DATA**

```
d = structure(list(Id = 1:7,
                   Brand1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L),
                   Brand2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L),
                   Brand3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
                   Brand4 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)),
              class = "data.frame",
              row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with matrix multiplication. Using d.b's data:

```
dmat = as.matrix(d[-1])
count = t(dmat) %*% dmat
count
#        Brand1 Brand2 Brand3 Brand4
# Brand1      4      3      0      3
# Brand2      3      3      0      2
# Brand3      0      0      3      2
# Brand4      3      2      2      5
apply(count, 2, function(x) x / max(x))
#        Brand1    Brand2    Brand3 Brand4
# Brand1   1.00 1.0000000 0.0000000    0.6
# Brand2   0.75 1.0000000 0.0000000    0.4
# Brand3   0.00 0.0000000 1.0000000    0.4
# Brand4   0.75 0.6666667 0.6666667    1.0
```